# Return list of users in profile

Tags: python, django

I would like users classified as students to be able to view all the mentors/teachers profiles along with their linkedin links in their profile pages

This is what i have tried. This is my views.py (students.py):

```
#get list of mentors
def mentor_list(request):
    mentor_list = []
    users = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)
    mentor = Mentor.objects.get()
    for mentor in users:
        data = mentor.get_decoded()
        mentor_list.append(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=mentor_list)

def render_mentor_list():
    return {'users': mentor_list() }
```

and my html file:

```
...
    {% if users %}
    <ul class="user-list">
        {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</li>
        <li>{{ mentor.linkedin }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
...
```

and models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
```

Currently nothing is appearing in the student profile (the html)

**UPDATE**

I have made edits to my views.py file after reading through some of the Django documentation, not sure if i am on the right track- still having the same issue

```
def mentor_list(request):
    mentors = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True).select_related('mentor')
    template_name = 'classroom/students/app-student-dashboard.html'
    context = {'mentors': mentors}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Here is the updated template:

```
<ul class="user-list" id="mentors">
    {% for user in mentors %}
    <li>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</li>
    <li>{{ user.mentor.linkedin }}</li>
</ul>
```

and urls.py:

```
path('students/', include(([
    path('', students.dashboard, name='quiz_list'),
    path('logout', students.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path('dashboard', students.dashboard, name='app-student-dashboard'),
    path('directory_grid', students.directory_grid, name='app-directory-grid'),
    path('take_course', students.take_course, name='app-take-course'),
    path('edit_user', students.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
    path('mentors', students.mentor_list, name='mentor'),
], 'classroom'), namespace='students')),
```

Comment: how did you pass the context data to template from view?

Comment: What is `mentor = Mentor.objects.get()` supposed to do?

Comment: You need return a `context` in `render_mentor_list`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem get the link to the mentor's linkedin profile - the one they entered when they signed up

Comment: @ArakkalAbu what do you mean

Comment: @Emm: but this will aim to fetch a `Mentor` object into memory and raise an error if there is no `Mentor` record, or there are *multiple* ones. So for the application in production, that will (nearly) always be the case.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what can I do as an alternative

Comment: You only need to return `User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True).select_related('mentor')` into your template's context, and then in your template when you loop through all the users, you can do `{{ user.mentor.linkedin}}`. All of your view code makes no sense whatsoever. It's not clear which is your view, the `mentor_list(request)` isn't returning a proper response and `render_mentor_list()` doesn't take a `request` parameter so it can't be a view either.

Comment: You should do the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/), you would have seen [this step](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) where you learn how to write a view that renders a list.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have made changes based on your comments and the link you sent

Comment: Your context variable is now `mentors` not `users` so I’m your template you need to loop through `mentors`. So now fix your template.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks, did that but still not seeing any of the user names

Comment: Show us the updated template

Comment: @dirkgroten done

Comment: And you removed `{% if users %}`?

Comment: @dirkgroten yeah, i removed that

Comment: That’s not possible. If the html you’re showing is for the template in your view this should work. And if this view is the one being called. You’re sure your request gets routed to `mentor_list`? Check urls.py

Comment: @dirkgroten I added what I have written in urls.py to the question

Comment: So this is when you fetch /students/mentors/?

Comment: @dirkgroten yeah. got it to work now thanks so much!